# How to display a QListWidget Item

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

I am running the below code:

```
    self.myList = QListWidget()
    for i in range(3):
        self.Item = QListWidgetItem()
        self.name = 'A'+'%04d'% i
        self.Item.setText(self.name)
        self.myList.addItem(self.Item)
    print self.myList.selectedItems()
```

it prints an empty list:

```
[]
```

Please suggest where I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to QT docs (i've used c++ ones, but it's ok for python bridge as well),

```
QList<QListWidgetItem *> QListWidget::selectedItems () const
Returns a list of all selected items in the list widget.
```

This means, that `print self.myList.selectedItems()` will output all the list of items user was selected, not all the items are in widget.

You can try to use `count()` to get number of items and `item(number)` to get one.